# I would like to reopen this question

Tags: support

I would like to reopen

[How do I shutdown the Host over ssh on ESXi 5 so it shuts down the guests properly?](https://serverfault.com/questions/349846/how-do-i-shutdown-all-vms-and-the-host-over-ssh-on-esxi-5-properly)

It is not a duplicate.

What can i do?

Comment: Your question seems like a duplicate. Can you explain why it's not the case? Stating why might enlighten a mod here so that he reopens your question..

Comment: OK Thank you. Someone already unblocked the question. Very nice.

Comment: Laf, at the time I posted this here I had already expanded and explained.

Answer (score 10):

1. Please don't edit out the system-generated "Possible Duplicate" link. You should never do that. From the [revision history](https://serverfault.com/posts/349846/revisions) it seems that this was probably accidental, but I still think it's worth mentioning.
2. Explain why it's not a duplicate. Add a paragraph to your question that states why it's not, so it's really obvious. Then, `flag` your question for moderator attention and ask them to reopen it, pointing to your edit.

Comment: Answsering youre No 2: it is obvious to someone who reads it that it is not a duplicate, it is a different question and if you read the first version you can see that. The one who should explain was the person who in the beginning marked this as a duplicate. Although I could understand that one person makes a mistake, I cannot understand that 3 others followed him, this can only mean they juwst like to klick around and do not really read the underlying case, they just trusted in the first persons (the one who voted duplicate first) opinion. But this is misuse of their admin position.

Comment: It is not the goal of needing more than one vote for closing that they just klick without reading., The goal is that they check by themselves and if they do it cannot happen so easily that such an obvious mistake happens.

Answer (score 6):

Because your question was originally posted on ServerFault, I suggest you post your argument to [Meta.ServerFault](https://meta.serverfault.com/). There, post your question and the question marked as duplicate, and explain why you think they are not the same. The users on ServerFault with sufficient reputation to open/close questions can then judge and possibly re-open your post.